# Why can't I get my sticker header to stay always on top of my content?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, z-index

I'm building a website on Wordpress using a theme called Frejya. There's a sticky header that appears when you've scrolled past the main header, and then scroll up. It's supposed to appear above all the site content. But there's one section of content that plays with z-index to make a text box appear over an image, and this box appears *above* the sticky header.

Take a look here:
https://rachaelscarpelliphotography.com

I would think adding a higher z-index to the #mini-header (the container div of the sticky header) would fix the issue, but it doesn't.

I've tried doing some research, and it seems that it may have something to do with the way z-index applies to elements related to their parents, or possibly to the *position* value of one of these elements, but I'm having a hard time figuring this one out.

Comment: Please add meaningful code to your question. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Reproducible example (or MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Use this below css**

```
header.sticky{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9999
}

header #logo,
header .cont_primary_menu.hide_mobile {
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

header.sticky #logo {
    padding-top: 1.4rem;
}

header.sticky .cont_primary_menu.hide_mobile {
    padding-bottom: 15px;
}
```

**For make the header sticky add below js code**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var header = $('header');
    var containerHeader = $('#container header');
    
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
            header.addClass('sticky');
        } else {
            header.removeClass('sticky');
        }
    });
});
```